# STM8S - Connect to ADXL345 Acceleration Sensor via Hardware SPI

Tags: sensor, spi, stm8

After software SPI didn't work out I am now trying to connect to the ADXL345 acceleration sensor via hardware SPI of the STM8S103F3. But, of course, problems appeared again, why not.
This is my SPI-Init code:

```
void initSPIMaster(){
    GPIOC->DDR = (1<<MOSI) | (1<<SCK) | (0<<MISO); //MOSI & SCK output, MISO input
    GPIOC->CR1 = (1<<MOSI) | (1<<SCK); //MOSI& SCK push-pull

    GPIOA->DDR |= (1<<CS); //set CS as output
    GPIOA->CR1 |= (1<<CS); //set CS as push-pull
    GPIOA->ODR |= (1<<CS); //turn CS high

    SPI->CR2 = 0b00000000; //2-line unidirectional, Hardware-Slave  management
    SPI->CR1 = 0b01111111; //Enable CPHA, CPOL, MASTER; Baudrate: f/256, SPI Enable
}
```

This is my SPI-Transmit function to write data to the `DR`-Register:

```
void SPITransmit(uint8_t data){
    while(!(SPI->SR & (1<<1))){
        nop(); //wait until transmit buffer is empty
    }
    SPI->DR = data;
    while((SPI->SR & (1<<7))){
        nop(); //wait until not busy
    }
}
```

This is my SPIReceive function to read data from the `DR`-Register:

```
uint8_t SPIReceive(){
    uint8_t registerValue;
    while((SPI->SR & (1<<7))){
        nop(); //wait until not busy
    }
    while(!(SPI->SR & (1<<0))){
        nop(); //wait until receive buffer is not empty
    }
    registerValue = (SPI->DR);
    nop();
    return registerValue;
}
```

As a initial test I tried to read the DEVID register of the ADXL345 (`0x00`), it should return `229` as decimal value. And indeed, it did, this is my function to read a register:

```
void getValueFromRegister(uint8_t reg, uint8_t *val){
    uint8_t transmitValue = (0x80 | reg);
    uint8_t receivedValue = 0;

    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<CS); //CS low
    SPITransmit(transmitValue); //write 'read' command
    delay_ms(10);
    receivedValue = SPIReceive();
    GPIOA->ODR |= (1<<CS); //CS high

    delay_ms(10);
    *val = receivedValue;
}
```

I also enabled the ADXL345 with this code:

```
void initADXL345(){
    //enable measurements
    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<CS); //turn CS low
    SPITransmit(0x2D);
    SPITransmit(0x08);
    GPIOA->ODR |= (1<<CS); //turn CS high
    delay_ms(5);

    //set FULL_RES & 16g-Range
    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<CS); //turn CS low
    SPITransmit(0x31);
    SPITransmit(0b00001011);
    GPIOA->ODR |= (1<<CS); //turn CS high
}
```

So the next logical step would be to read data from the data registers (`0x32`-`0x37`), so I did (`x`, `y`, `z` are global values of type `int16_t`):

```
void getXYZValues(){
    uint8_t x0,x1,y0,y1,z0,z1;
    getValueFromRegister(0x32, &x0);
    delay_ms(10);
    getValueFromRegister(0x33, &x1);
    delay_ms(10);
    getValueFromRegister(0x34, &y0);
    delay_ms(10);
    getValueFromRegister(0x35, &y1);
    delay_ms(10);
    getValueFromRegister(0x36, &z0);
    delay_ms(10);
    getValueFromRegister(0x37, &z1);

    x = ((x1<<8) | x0);
    y = ((y1<<8) | y0);
    z = ((z1<<8) | z0);
}
```

The problem now is:

I always get the value `-6683` (decimal) for every axis! And these value isn't even changing if I move the sensor!

For gods sake, why is it so horrible to work with this sensor?

I thought about that maybe `CPOL` or `CPHA` is the problem but according to the datasheet they should both be enabled (as I did).

Any ideas, why this is not working? I am really frustrated and I try to get it to work for weeks (if I add the days from my first try with software SPI).

Comment: There is a very big clue in the data; -6683 is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFE5E5, or 0xE5E5 when limited to a 16 bit value; the ID register returns *E5* in its ID. This makes me think you are simply getting repeats of the ID register reads; try reading back the setup registers (0x2D and 0x31) and check they are indeed being set up as you think. If not, it implicates the transmit function.

Comment: You are completely right! I get the value `8` (decimal) for `0x2D` and `0x31` register even though `0x31` should have the value `11` (decimal).
But how do i know if the `transmit` or `receive` function is faulty?

Comment: The receive function is *working* for a device ID read, and I would therefore surmise it is operational. That leaves the transmit function. Note that the datasheet recommends a burst read of all 6 registers in a single transaction, but it should not be necessary unless you require guaranteed precision. I would suggest a breakpoint in the transmit function immediately after the SPI block data register is loaded; see what is in there. It is interesting that the value in the second register is the same as the *first write*

Comment: If i write `0x31` to the DR-Register i get `0x0B` as the value of the SPI Data register. Why?

Comment: 0x0B is what you are trying to write (0b00001011 = 0x0B)

Comment: I got rid of the previous comment; apparently, the transmit buffer is being properly loaded, but it is not necessarily being loaded up in the ADXL345; what is the actual communication speed?

Comment: @PeterSmith to your first comment after mine:

But i read `0x0B` after i try to write `0x31` as you can see here: https://picload.org/image/rgoglrwg/spi_stm8.png

I set the speed to f/125, so it should be 128kHz.

Comment: @binaryBigInt - "But how do i know if the transmit or receive function is faulty?" - Get another tool to observe the SPI communications "on the wire" e.g. a 'scope with built-in SPI decoding, or a logic analyser etc. Something like that will pay for itself, by quickly showing the causes of problems like this.

Comment: @SamGibson Fortunately i have a Logic Analyzer here, i used it before to determine if my SPI transmit works correctly, here is one data transmission to read register `0x31`: https://picload.org/image/rgoglawl/spi_adxl345.png

Comment: @binaryBigInt - OK, so using that logic analyser, you can (mostly) answer your question, about whether the transmit function is OK or not, by checking what was actually sent "on the wire". Although, as I have just discussed in another topic (which reminded me about some past experiences of my own) there can *sometimes* be analog signal quality issues which you will only see on a 'scope, and which are invisible on a logic analyser. Nevertheless, as far as the *programmatic* part is concerned, the logic analyser display will show whether your transmit code is doing what you expect, or not.

Comment: I think it sends the right data but i am wondering why it still doesn't work.

Comment: Lol this stuff even prints the same value if i pull the MOSI cable off! There is definately something wrong with the SPI Dataregister. The reading stuff seems to work because if i just read the data from SPI DR if the RXNE-Bit is '0' i get the register numbers i want to read (so `0x2D` & `0x31`).

Comment: The ADXL345 Sensor still returns values even though there are no commands for him to send anything because i pulled the MOSI cable off. If i disconnect the CLK-Pin too i only get a single `high` from the ADXL345.

Comment: @binaryBigInt.  This is definitely a bug in your code, not the ADXL345, since you can see transmit data looks OK and since you "read" data back even with the cables unplugged.  My guess is after you read the data register, you need to reset it or something.  A couple suggestions: 1) you are kinda redoing work that the manufacturers often do for you.  Check this out  http://www2.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software.html   there are several examples of firmware using SPI peripheral on your hardware.

Comment: @binaryBigInt Check out application note AN2673 on the same site, it goes with the firmware examples.  They give you examples of using SPI master hardware.  Lastly 2) if you paste your code again, I'll try to take a look.  It's very suspicious, as others have pointed out, that you read in the first values you wrote.  That should be pointing you to the issue.

Comment: @binaryBigInt  Sir, start from a known good point.  I have downloaded the program at https://my2.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm8-embedded-software/stsw-stm8049.license%3d1462820180461.html  Did you take a look at the main.c for their SPI example?  Start there.  In fact, try to get just that running on your hardware (compiling), then modify it to read your DEVID.  If you look at it for an example, you probably forgot to include "stm8s_lib.h" like they did.  Or something else, but they will give you working code so try to get that working first.

Comment: @while1 `stm8s_lib.h` does nothing elses than including the appropriate header files but because i know that i need `stm8s_spi.h` if i wanna use SPI i already included that in my project, the error still exists.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to point you towards the forest here and you keep ramming your head into the same tree.  My point wasn't about stm8s_lib.h specifically, but rather that there could be other things you are missing, and so to start from their code which should be a known working state.  Rather, you try to munge what you think you need into your program but it isn't working for you as shown by your basic linker error above.  If you don't want to try my suggestion of starting with their code, that's fine, then I suggest google is your friend for linker errors.

Comment: I am just wondering why STM doesn't provide all functions or files i need to create a SPI connection? I downloaded their Standard Peripheral Library and now it looks like it misses a lot of header files! Why do i have to download a 8 year old example project to get them?